# IIS 7.5 setting error page with iis stopped

Tags: iis7

Can you set a custom Error page if IIS is stopped or recycling for an extended period of time?

Comment: What do you mean if IIS is stopped?

Answer (score 1):

If IIS is stopped, then it won't serve any pages, custom or built-in.

Comment: That's what I would figure too. When I stop the site in the console, the SSL port 443 stops responding completely -- but port 80 still responds with a 404 Not Found error for any request. Surprise!